# MEF doesn't work unless I run as Administrator

Tags: security, mef

When I run my application in Release mode, MEF does not import my exports "Unless" I run as Administrator. I tried adding a manifest setting level=requireAdministrator but this didn't help. Here is my MEF code...I'm running Windows 7 .Net 4.0.

```
 var compositionBatch = new CompositionBatch();
 compositionBatch.AddPart(this);
 _aggregateCatalog = new AggregateCatalog();
 _aggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(_solverDirectoryCatalog);
compositionContainer.Compose(compositionBatch);
```

Comment: Did anybody else see the "Unless" in quotes and think of the quote from the Lorax? :)

Answer (score 0):

That _solverDirectoryCatalog above was created via prefacing the folder with "environment.currentdirectory". This is what was failing...it should have referenced "appdomain.currentdomain.basedirectory"